# Unique list of links from HTML using Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

So I have a script that extracts all links from a web site, I thought that converting to a list would do the job of making sure I only returned unique links, but there are still dups in the output (ie 'www.commerce.gov/' and 'www.commerce.gov') the code is not picking up the trailing characters. Below is my code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re
import csv

req = Request("https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html")
html_page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")

prettyhtml = soup.prettify()
Html_file = open("U:\python_intro\popest_html.txt","w")
Html_file.write(prettyhtml)
Html_file.close()

links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile(r'^(?:http|ftp)s?://')}):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

links = set(links)

myfile = "U:\python_stuff\links.csv"

with open(myfile, "w") as output:
writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
for a in links:
    writer.writerow([a])
```

Comment: What is your definition of a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You mean "converting to a set" not a list.
2. You can remove any possible trailing `'/'`:

   ```
   links.append(link.get('href').rstrip('/'))
   ```
3. Or even better, build a set from the first place:

   ```
   links = set()
   for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile(r'^(?:http|ftp)s?://')}):
       links.add(link.get('href').rstrip('/'))
   ```

Comment: yes, sorry. converting to a set. I'm still learning, about a week into learning python. I took your advice and built it as a set in the first place. Works like a charm. Thank you!